# call bpel process from jsp

Tags: web-services, jsp, bpel

I've created a BPEL process and tested it with soapUI, it works and gives the right results. Now I need to call it from a J2EE web application, I've googled how this could be done but I'm totally confused, I don't know if I need to use SOAP or JAX-WS or anything else. I've found on [Oracle web site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11036_01/integrate.1013/b28981/invoke.htm) a nice tuto that explains how to invoke BPEL with the class Locator that uses orabpel.jar but I couldn't find where to download this jar to test it, and I'm not sure if it works only with Oracle BPEL Manager or can be used with ODE

EDIT: eclipse and tomcat are acting weird I can't explain why but I managed to create the ws client but it didn't put all the classes in the same package, DeclarationPortTypeProxy was in a package declaration and the rest were in declaration_pkg

I have the error :

> The type DeclarationPortTypeProxy must implement the inherited
>   abstract method
>   DeclarationPortType.process(DeclarationRequest)

When I try to run it anyway it says

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path
>   [/ClientDeclaration] threw exception java.io.IOException: (404)Not
>   Found

What does it mean ?

Thanks in advance

PS: I have Tomcat 8 and Apache ODE 2

Comment: Whats your WSDL URL of your BPEL process?

Comment: it's http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/declaration?wsdl where declaration is the name of my process, the syntax is correct and eclipse finds it but then it says that it's invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to genereate the client, I really don't understand why but I just had to reinstall Tomcat and ODE, I should have thought about it sooner, it drove me nuts!